# Stuck on subscribing to parse.com in windows 8.1 app

Tags: windows, parse-platform

I am testing the Parse API and is trying to create an Windows 8.1 app.

I can signup and login, get current installation, but when I try to subscribe to a channel, the application freeze.

Using this code:

```
var ins = ParseInstallation.CurrentInstallation;
Debug.WriteLine(ins.InstallationId);

ins.AddUniqueToList("channels", "Test");
await ins.SaveAsync();
```

The `SaveaAync` does not ever return.

Anybody know how to solve this?

/Christian

Comment: same, here , that or the ParsePush.SubscribeAsync(""); gets me stuck

Comment: Any solution for this? I have the same problem.